# Sequential row numbering skipping blank values and formulas using array formula

Tags: google-sheets, count, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I want to count each row that has a value in the following cell of that row ignoring blank values and formulas using an array formula.

In my mind, this should work `=ArrayFormula(IF(D5:D<>"",ROW(D5:D)-4,))`, but of course, this is not sequential as it also counts, but does not print, the blank rows.

I found this `=IF(D5<>"",COUNTA($D$5:D5),"")`, but I would have to drag it down the entire column, which I would prefer to avoid, but can do.  At this point, I'm just curious if it can be done in an array formula.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be looking at data starting from D5, you can try this:

```
=arrayformula(if(len(D5:D),SORT(ROW(D5:D),SORT(ROW(D5:D),D5:D,1),1)-4,""))
```

[image]